# IllegalStateException orientation change while performing filter query serach

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-searchmanager, android-filter

I have implemented search in a `listview` using `searchview` and `setFilterQueryProvider` on custom `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

inside a onActivityCreated of my fragment, i am setting filter by following code

```
myAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider(){

                @Override
                public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {


                    returnget Activity().getBaseContext().getContentResolver().
                            query(  Uri.parse("content://com.DBProvider/getEmployeeByName"),
                            EMP.PROJECTION, EMP.EMP_NAME + " LIKE '"+ constraint+"%'", null, null);;

                }


            });

       // this code is outside `setFilterQueryProvider`
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(EMP_INFO.ID, null, this);
```

now the issue is , when i change the orientation i am getting IllegalStateException exception.

```
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery 
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:34)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:67)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:290)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:262)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at net.sqlcipher.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:193)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToPosition(CursorWrapper.java:162)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToPosition(CursorWrapper.java:162)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:247)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-12 18:08:46.215: E/AndroidRuntime(3242):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT

i found that following line is causing the problem at the time of orientation change as its inside `onActivityCreated` so how can i prevent this , on orientation change i want to be on last search item ( previous state).

```
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(EMP_INFO.ID, null, this);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this code in AndroidManifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Hope not to late ;)